# Зачем передавать window в качестве аргумента?

Tags: javascript

```
(function(){...})(); // Это понятно.
(function(){...})(window); // ??? причём без параметра
```

Например Google Analytics так делает: https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

Comment: @Даниил Объект `window` будет вызываться, даже если его не передавать в аргумете.

Comment: ну это понятно. [Статья](https://toddmotto.com/what-function-window-document-undefined-iife-really-means/)

Comment: Статья - [ENG stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020479/what-advantages-does-using-functionwindow-document-undefined-windo)

Comment: Еще одна [статья](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716069/how-does-this-javascript-jquery-syntax-work-function-window-undefined)

Comment: В первой статье пишет что это оптимизация: Local variables are faster to resolve than the global variables, but this is on a huge scale and you’ll never notice the speed increase

Comment: А вы уверены в этом "причём без параметра"?

Comment: @vp_arth Ну да. https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Минификация

```js
((w, d) => {
  // Каждое появление w здесь экономит 5 символов
  w.console.log(d.title);
})(window, document);
```

2. Тестируемость

```js
const somePlugin = (window) => ({
  // код плагина использует window
  log(...args) { window.console.log(...args); }
});


const mock = {log: [], console: {log: (...args) => mock.log.push(args)}}
// но реализацию window можно заменить
let p = somePlugin(mock);
p.log(1, 2, 3);
p.log(4);

console.log(JSON.stringify(mock.log));
```

3. Микрооптимизации

> Доступ к локальной переменной чуть быстрее, чем к глобальной(но это не точно) =)

Comment: Да, наверно что нибудь из второго.

Answer (score 1):

Если функция использует `this` – это подразумевает работу с объектом. Но и прямой вызов `func()` технически возможен, a в режиме `use strict` вместо глобального объекта `this` будет `undefined`.

```js
function func() {
  "use strict";
  alert( this ); // выведет undefined (кроме IE9-)
}

func();
```